# Is it possible to access OpenCV OCL (OpenCL) methods from python (cv2)?

Tags: python, opencv, opencl

From what I can tell, there's no way to access OpenCV's OpenCL (OCL) module from the python cv2 bindings.  Does anyone know of a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unfortunately, - no way.

opencv uses special Mat types for this, ocl::Mat or cuda::Mat ,

and those are not exposed to the wrappers (so, same problem for java and matlab)

Comment: update: there's the so-called 'T-api' in master(3.0), which will allow gpu optimizations in the very same way, SIMD and such are handled already. but that's the future...